# How overflow menu works

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to add an overflow menu to my app, but it doesn't work like i would like.

Indeed, the overflow button is not displayed on the right corner of the screen into the action bar,  but when i click on the setting button of my device (Samsung Galaxy S3) it works. A kind of tab appears at the bottom of my screen and when i select it, a popup with my four items menu is displayed at the middle of the screen.

I would like to understand how can i manage this, to get the same result as the number three in this picture :

[image]

manifest.xml :

```
 <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="7"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

styles.xml :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

res > menu > menu_maps_styles.xml (which is my overflow menu) :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:GoogleMapAndroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <!-- Normal map -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_normal_map"
        GoogleMapAndroid:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_normal_map"/>

    <!-- Satellite map -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_satellite_map"
        GoogleMapAndroid:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_satellite_map"/>

    <!-- Terrain map -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_terrain_map"
        GoogleMapAndroid:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_terrain_map"/>

    <!-- Hybrid map -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_hybrid_map"
        GoogleMapAndroid:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_hybrid_map"/>

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_maps_styles, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

According to your orignal post, and the discussion in the comments below, the solution was to change your style as follows:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

This resolved your issue, because, your project didn't need the `AppCompat` library:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

However if you want to use the `AppCompat`, I let my original answer below and I suggest you to read this: [Setting Up the Action Bar: Support Android 2.1 and Above](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html#ApiLevel7).
Good dev.

---

**Orignal Answer**

As you can read on the Documentation:

> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses **a custom namespace defined in the  tag**. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So **you must use your own namespace as a prefix** for all attributes defined by the support library.

Then, you layout must to be:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
  <!-- Normal map -->
  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_normal_map"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_normal_map"/>

    <!-- Satellite map -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_satellite_map"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/action_satellite_map"/>

    <!-- Terrain map -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_terrain_map"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/action_terrain_map"/>

    <!-- Hybrid map -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_hybrid_map"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="@string/action_hybrid_map"/>
</menu>
```

([See the details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu)) The onCreateOptionsMenu method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_maps_styles, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Your *more item* (id a_More) is useless because the overflow menu button is implemented via the extension of the class. It's an automatic widget.
Also, make sure your **Activity extends `ActionBarActivity`** and you have **the right imports**:

- *import android.view.Menu;*
- *import android.view.MenuItem;*
- *import android.view.MenuInflater;*
- *import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;*

Make also sure that you have updated the last version of SDK.
Your theme needs to be as follows:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

And now, you can if you want, use the AppCompat on API 7 and higher:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: I've done the modifications that you told me but it has not changed. The button doesn't appear on the action bar at the right corner. I updated my post with the modifications. But the device's button always works and display my items menu when i click on.

Comment: Try to remove this uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow". Then, add the order in category in your items. Also you did extend your MainActivity with ActionBarActivity, right?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. So i tried all that you adviced me but it didn't work.. i'm sorry :( 

When i go to android:minSdkVersion="7" i have got an error on (which is into my onCreate method)

gMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); and i have to Add @SupressLint 'NewApi' to MainActivity or clear all lint markers. I guess my SDK version is ok because i updated it to use google map v2.

Comment: However.. I'm asking a question: why do you want to use the AppCompat because you can have the ActionBar without it since API 11? As your original post, you had `android:minSdkVersion="11"`. Maybe you can try it but in change your Activity with extends FragmentActivity and use the theme `@style/Theme.Holo.Light"`.. who knows. - Anyway, good luck.

Comment: i tried your last comment, i didn't work, then i tried to redo everything and now it's work good.... Thank you again for your detailed help

Comment: Ahh glad to read that! So indeed it was the theme I'll update my answer according to the discussion in comments. I knew it was a simple thing ;) Happy coding!